# Reference, Shallow, and Deep Copy

Tags: java, arrays, methods, deep-copy, stringbuffer

I have been researching and reading what these three (Reference copy, Shallow copy and Deep copy) methods do and how to create them; and I am still having a hard time understanding how to implement the said methods in my code.

The first method suppose to be a reference method (refCopy), the second should be a shallow method (shalCopy) and last a deep copy method(deepCopy). Not sure if these are correct. Any help on how to execute these copies correctly will be greatly appreciated.

This is my code so far:

```
public class ArrayRefCopy implements Cloneable {
    private static int n = 3;
    private static StringBuffer[] buf = new StringBuffer[4];
    public static void main(String[] args){

        StringBuffer[] hel = new StringBuffer[n];
        hel[0] = new StringBuffer("hello");
        hel[1] = new StringBuffer("hallo");
        hel[2] = new StringBuffer("hey");

        refCopy(hel);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hel));
        shalCopy(hel);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hel));


    }

    public static StringBuffer[] refCopy(StringBuffer[] bra){

        StringBuffer[] ber = bra;
        return ber;
    }

    public static StringBuffer[] shalCopy(StringBuffer[] bar){

        return buf = bar;
    }

    public static StringBuffer[] deepCopy(StringBuffer[] bri){

        StringBuffer[] deep = new StringBuffer[n];
        return deep = bri.clone();
    }
}
```

=========================================================================

I changed the last two methods to this (created objects in them):

```
public static StringBuffer[] shalCopy(StringBuffer[] bar){
        StringBuffer[] buf = new StringBuffer[n];
        return buf = Arrays.copyOf(bar, n);
    }

    public static StringBuffer[] deepCopy(StringBuffer[] bri){

        StringBuffer[] deep = new StringBuffer[n];
        return deep = bri.clone();
    }
```

But when I do this:

```
StringBuffer[] hel = new StringBuffer[n];
        hel[0] = new StringBuffer("hello");
        hel[1] = new StringBuffer("hallo");
        hel[2] = new StringBuffer("hey");

        StringBuffer[] hal = new StringBuffer[n];
        hal = deepCopy(hel);


        System.out.println(hal.equals(hel));
```

It gives me false. I thought clone would completely copy the object with its values. Why is it giving me false?

**UPDATE:**

```
public static StringBuffer[] shalCopy(StringBuffer[] bar){
        StringBuffer[] buf = new StringBuffer[bar.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < bar.length; i++){
            buf[i] = bar[i];
        }

            return buf;
        }




    public static StringBuffer[] deepCopy(StringBuffer[] bri){

        StringBuffer[] deep = new StringBuffer[bri.length];
        for(int i=0; i < bri.length; i++){
            bri[i] = new StringBuffer(bri[i]);
            deep[i] = bri[i];
        }

        return deep;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Reference copy = A new variable pointing to the original object.

Shallow copy = Create a new copy of the original object and assign identical values to its primitive properties but use the same references as the original object for the properties that refer to other objects.

Deep copy = Create a new copy of the original object and recursively create new copies for every object reference in the original object references chain.

Example:

```
class C {
int b;
A ref1; // in shallow copy, use the same object reference. In deep copy, create a copy on this class instance
}
```

---

To answer your second question on why `hal.equals(hel)` returns false: It's because this is the same as == check. To compare two arrays contents, you'd have to use `Arrays.equals(array1, array2);`

Comment: is Arrays.equals giving true for the three ? If it's the case, yes it's right as the Arrays.equals equality checks for the values of the elements inside the array. So as the arrays point to the same object in reference copy, they obviously have the same values for their elements.

Comment: Now they are giving me true for all methods, is that right? I thought for a reference copy it would give me false. Is it true because, even though they are different references, they are still pointing to the same object?

Answer (score 2):

Your `refCopy()` is fine.

`shalCopy()` needs to construct a `new` array, then copy in the input `StringBuffer` references so it shares those `StringBuffer` objects. Write a loop or use `arrayCopy`.

`deepCopy()` needs to construct a `new` array and then make copies of all the input `StringBuffers`.

Can you fill in the details? If we do your assignment for you, you might not learn from it as well.

**Update:** Your updated `shalCopy()` method gets the right result in this case but (1) it should use `bar.length` (its input array length) instead of assuming its input array has length `n`, and (2) the first assignment `buf = new StringBuffer[n]` is pointless and misleading since the code immediately replaces that with another array. Also, this will be more instructive if you write an explicit loop rather than call `Arrays.copyOf()`.

Your updated `deepCopy()` does not get the right result, and it repeats the above problems. `clone()` is not what's needed, is not so useful in general, and does not shed any light on the problem at hand, that is, it's not instructive here. Instead, try constructing a new array and using a loop to (deep) copy all the StringBuffer objects, not their references.

Here's how you can tell if your code works:

- A **reference copy** `dest = refCopy(source)` should make the variable `dest` refer to the same instance as `source`. So changing e.g. `dest[0] = null` will also change `source[0]`.
- A **shallow copy** `dest = shalCopy(source)` should make the variable `dest` refer to a new array that contains the very same instances that are in `source`. So changing `dest[0] = null` will not change `source[0]`, but modifying a shared instance, e.g. `dest[1].append("!")` will modify `source[1]`.
- A **deep copy** `dest = deepCopy(source)` should make the variable `dest` refer to a separate array that contains separate instances that are not in `source`. So neither of the above changes to `dest` will modify `source`.

Comment: Yes, I know. I think this is all the information I need. I am starting to get it. Thank you. I might post my new code in a bit just to make sure, I comprehend these terms.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to how to write a loop for this. What I've come up is this:     for(int i = 0; i < bar.length; i++){
   StringBuffer[] buf = bar[i];

Comment: I tried casting and it still gave me the error of "Type mismatch: cannot convert from StringBuffer to StringBuffer[]." Which I get it since I basically trying to convert the values to an array. How do I go about this. My logic was to iterate through bar so that each value is add/copied to buf.

Comment: Outside the loop, declare and initialize the result array: `StringBuffer[] output = new StringBuffer[input.length];` where I've used more meaningful variable names. This means changing the method arg name to `input`. Inside the `shalCopy()` loop, copy each array element reference: `output[i] = input[i]`. Do not declare another array variable there. Inside the `deepCopy()` loop is similar, but duplicating the `StringBuffer` instance.

Comment: This is way trickier than I thought. What's wrong with this loop, why doesn't work?public static StringBuffer[] shalCopy(StringBuffer[] bar){
  StringBuffer[] buf = new StringBuffer[bar.length];
  for(int i: bar){
   buf[i] = bar[i];
   
   return buf;
  }

Comment: You're very close. Write the loop control like you did above, `for (int i = 0; i < bar.length; ++i)` and ensure there's one `}` to end the copy loop, then the `return buf;` statement, then another `}` to end the method.

Comment: Yes! it worked. Thank you. I'll update it. And I tried the deep copy as well, would the last method be considered a deep copy now?

Comment: It would if it didn't modify the argument array. The loop body should just do `deep[i] = new StringBuffer(bri[i]);`. Don't store into the argument array `bri`.